# All possible permutations of a NxN matrix in Java

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, permutation

I want to generate all possible permutations of a matrix using recursion.
For example 2x2 matrix will have 24 possibilities.

```
1 2  1 2  1 3  1 4
3 4, 4 3, 2 4, 2 3....24 possibilities.
```

Here is my code. The logic looks fine but I could get only four different possibilities. I hope someone can help me out with this.

```
public class NewClass 
{
public static int LENGTH=2,count=0;

public static int check_if_array_is_fully_filled(int[][] a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

public static int[][] initialize_all_zeros(int[][] a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
public static void display(int[][] a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("********");
    count++;
}

public static void generate(int[][] a, int value_to_enter, int done)
{        
    if(done == 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(a[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    a[i][j]=value_to_enter;
                    value_to_enter++;
                    int v = check_if_array_is_fully_filled(a);
                    if(v == 1)
                    {
                        done = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        generate(a,value_to_enter,0);
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }                        
    }
    if(done == 1)
    {
        display(a);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] agrs)
{
    int[][] a;
    for(int i=0;i<LENGTH;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<LENGTH;j++)
        {
            a = new int[LENGTH][LENGTH];
            a = initialize_all_zeros(a);
            a[i][j]=1;
            generate(a,2,0);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

Comment: please start by giving meaningful names to your variables and functions, so the code can be read.

Comment: 2x2 = 4. 4! = 24. permutations(n) = n!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily about combinatorics and permutations

Comment: @njzk2 I have edited. Could you help me now ?

Comment: @ControlAltDel So what do you suggest me to do instead ?

Comment: your algorithm is wrong. you are generating only `LENGTH*LENGTH` matrices.

Comment: @njzk2 Please also have a look at the `generate` function, which recursively generates matrices. So, it should produce `LENGTH*LENGTH !` matrices.

Comment: the recursive call to generate does not work, because since the call modifies the matrix, it is only called once. to observe this, look at the content of the matrix after the first call to `generate` inside the `generate` method.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks I understood. Is there a way to solve this array problem ?

Comment: you need to either rollback at the end of your `generate` function (remember the point where you set the value and set it back to 0), or make copies of your matrix. Also, you are incrementing `value_to_enter`, meaning your second iteration to `generate` will skip a value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recursive function for a 1d array using the same logic as you did. The 2d is more or less the same thing.

```
private static void generate(int[] values, int currentValue) {
    if (currentValue == values.length + 1) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == 0) {
            values[i] = currentValue;
            generate(values, currentValue + 1);
            values[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Call like so:

```
generate(new int[3], 1);
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Which should be encapsulated in a

```
public static void generate(int size) {
    generate(new int[size], 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My pseudo approach would be:

1. convert matrix to list
2. permute list
3. for each permutation of the list, convert list back to matrix.

You have not mentioned if all the elements in your matrix are unique. If they are not, then you need to remove duplicate lists from your permutation as well (need to filter after 2, before 3.

permute list:

1. The easiest way to understand this is by recursion.

The base step is when you have two numbers, the permutations are easy. it is (a,b) and (b,a)

To add a third element, you will add the element to all positions
e.g. permute(c,{(a,b), (b,a)}) = { (c,a,b), (a,c,b),(a,b,c), 
(c,b,a), (b,c,a), (b,a,c) }

so, you recursion will be permute(a,permutedlist)

for each b in permutedlist, add a to all possible positions in the list.