# Generating all possible Permutation matrices

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, permutation, combinatorics

Permutation matrices are matrices with exactly one 1 on each line and column.

Example:

(1 0 0)

(0 1 0)

(0 0 1)

I am trying to generate all possible permutations of a n-sized matrix but this seems harder to solve than expected. I tried swapping rows at first, but if you only swap rows of one initial matrix, you can't generate all possibilities. So I tried some recursion, but sadly I can't get my head through recursion. Does somebody have some advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All possible permutations of a NxN matrix in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549708/all-possible-permutations-of-a-nxn-matrix-in-java)

Comment: Sadly not working with this case of Permutation matrices

Comment: Can u provide a [mre] ?

Comment: Why did you closed that, it isn't duplicate of that...?

Comment: Got closed because of duplicate....it's not

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make an algorithm based on recursion, with this design:

```
public Collection<Matrix> permute(int n)
```

1. Base case is `n=1`: It returns a single matrix `{1}`.
2. The rest of cases must iterate from `i=0 to n-1`. On eeach iteration:

   - Call to `permute(n-1)` and iterate the returned list. On each iteration:

     - Convert the `n-1` matrix to a `n x n` matrix, inserting a row at position 0 and a column at position 0 (filled with 0).
     - Set an 1 in the `(0,0)` position.
     - Move the first **column** to the `i` position.

I suggest you could also make a battery of unit tests. Each one should check, at least, that the size of the collection returned by `permute(n)` has `n!` elements:

- 1->1
- 2->2
- 3->6
- 4->24